# validate Array of jsx in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to test the type of array of jsx elements as below

```
const test = [
    <div> sakira </div>,
    <div> killbill </div>
];
```

**Also Some Suggestions On Complex rendering of React Components with typescript validation**

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
import React from 'react';

const test: JSX.Element[] = [
    <div> sakira </div>,
    <div> killbill </div>
];
```